# Why is foo(1,2,3) not passed to varargs method foo(Object... ) as an Integer[]

Tags: java, variadic-functions, autoboxing

Please regard the following lines of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    foo(1,2,3);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    foo(new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3));
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    foo(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    foo(new Integer[] {new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)});
}

public static void foo(Object... bar) {
    System.out.println("bar instanceof Integer[]:\t" + (bar instanceof Integer[]));
    System.out.println("bar[0] instanceof Integer:\t" + (bar[0] instanceof Integer));
    System.out.println("bar.getClass().isArray():\t" + bar.getClass().isArray());
}
```

The output of this code snippet is:

```
bar instanceof Integer[]:   false
bar[0] instanceof Integer:  true
bar.getClass().isArray():   true
-------------------------------------
bar instanceof Integer[]:   false
bar[0] instanceof Integer:  true
bar.getClass().isArray():   true
-------------------------------------
bar instanceof Integer[]:   true
bar[0] instanceof Integer:  true
bar.getClass().isArray():   true
-------------------------------------
bar instanceof Integer[]:   true
bar[0] instanceof Integer:  true
bar.getClass().isArray():   true
```

And this confuses me quite a bit! I don't understand why in case of `foo(1,2,3)` the term `bar instanceof Integer[]` is false.

If in these cases bar is not an instance of `Integer[]` what else is it an instance of?

Comment: I think the first and the second should be Object array but not Integer array

Comment: Since you could pass a String for example to the varargs aswell it should originally be an `Object[]` and not an `Integer[]`. For the last two you are explicity passing an `Integer[]`, so your condition will be true now.

Comment: This is an interesting question! One suggestion: Try adding a test of `foo(new int[]{1,2,3});`. The result will go from confusing to weird!

Comment: @Lii oh well :D the `int[]` will be interpreted as a single object instead of wrapping all the `int`s! Nice addition!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- `foo(1,2,3);`

This one autoboxes `1`, `2` and `3` to `Integer`(s) and since they are `Object` sub-types, an `Object[]` array is created, consisting of three `Integer`s. An array `Object[]` is not `Integer[]` and that's why you get `false`.

---

- `foo(new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3));`

Here, no auto boxing applies, but in the end you will again have an array `Object[]` that consist of three `Integer`s. Again, `Object[]` is not `Integer[]` and that's why you get `false`.

---

- `foo(new Integer[]{1,2,3});`

Here you have **only one** argument, unlike the previous two cases, where you had three wrapped into one array. So, having only one argument `Integer[]`, at Runtime the comparison `bar instanceof Integer[]` will return `true`, because integers is what you actually have.

---

- `foo(new Integer[] {new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)});`

Same as the previous one - at Runtime you will check if the provided array `Integer[]` is an array of `Integer`s, which is `true`.

Comment: ah ok, i think i see my mistake now. I (falsely) assumed an `Object[]` which constists of only `Integers` would be an `Integer[]` (Thinking about it, that is of course wrong!) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2):

> the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException.

In your case the `Object[]` parameter cannot be cast to an `Integer[]` so it returns false.

Comment: To the cast: That's how I came to this problem in the first place ;)

Answer (score 3):

the case where bar is not an array of integer is because it is an array of Object as you specified in your `foo` method signature: `Object... args` is syntactic sugar for `Object[] args` and when resolving to this method the compiler will create an array of Object.

In order to always have an array of Integer you could change your `foo` method signature to `foo(Integer... args)`

Answer (score 3):

Varargs are just syntactic sugar for creating and passing arrays. Since you defined your method as

```
public static void foo(Object... bar)
```

Java creates an `Object[]` array for you if you call the method as `foo(1,2,3)` or `foo(new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3))`.

However, you can also pass your own array to a method which requires a varargs parameter. In this case Java does not create a new array for you, it just passes the array you created. In the last two calls you explicitly create an `Integer[]` array.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of calling `foo(1,2,3);` the compiler (in this case `javac`) generates the code `foo(new Object[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(2), new Integer(3)})`.

`javac` applies the rules for [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). The compiler generates an array of `Object` because `Object...` means `Object[]`. Therefore `bar` is not an instance of `Integer[]`. It is just syntactic sugar.